# Query DSL annotations not working on netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, seam, querydsl

I am using Netbeans 7.2 and JDK 1.6 on Mac Lion to create a maven project that uses queryDSL.

My pom.xml  has the following snippets

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>



            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/generated</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The following pom does not ensure my QueryDSL annotations are processed and the 'Q' classes are created.
The same settings are working fine on eclipse.

Any help much appreciated

Nandish

Comment: I think you found the answer in the Querydsl Google Group, could you provide it also here? Thanks.

Comment: The issue was resolved after adding javaee.jar and following the standard query dsl documentation to create the annotation processor https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/7f8AWdWvvmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution discussed in the following thread
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/7f8AWdWvvmg